# SML NJ - Polymorphic custom list type and summing the elements

Tags: polymorphism, sml, smlnj

I'm learning about polymorphism and SML. I'm a little unsure on how to handle summing of elements while keeping the function polymorphic.

Say if I have this definition...

```
datatype 'a customList = nothing | customL of 'a * 'a customList
```

and this list...

```
val a = customL(2, customL(1, customL(3, nothing)))
```

I figure I need to use (op +) because of the polymorphic handling but I can't get these to work...

```
fun addElements (op +) nothing = 0
|   addElements (op +) (customL(x, nothing) = x
|   addElements (op +) (customL(x, xs)) = x + addElements xs
```

I'm also thinking that handling of "nothing" may mess up the type as well?

Anyone able to help with getting this to work?

**Update**

I think I'm closer to it but I don't understand why I'm getting an error...

```
exception EmptyList

fun addElements (op + ) nothing = raise EmptyList
|   addElements (op + ) (customL(x, nothing)) = x
|   addElements (op + ) (customL(x, xs)) = let val rest_of_list = addElements (op +) xs
                                       in
                                          (op + ) (x, rest_of_list)
                                       end
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to do. SML doesn't support operator overloading and "generic" isn't a word that is used much in SML (other than in some fairly advanced areas involving signatures and functors). "polymorphic" is used more. You seem to want to write a sort of `fold` to work for your custom lists and you should be able to do so, but then `(op +)` would be one function that could be fed into your function, not something hard-wired into the definition. If you hard-wire it into the definition then it would only apply to either `ints` or `reals` (but not both).

Comment: Sorry - I corrected generics to polymorphism.  All I want is to be able to sum the elements of the list but support ints or reals.  I know that sml will by default treat the type as int unless I pass in (op +).  What do you mean by hard-wired?  I want the list to work with either customL(1, customL(2 or customL(1.2, custom(2.2 - either a list of ints or a list of reals

Comment: It isn't possible to write a function `f` in SML so that `f(1,2) = 3` and `f(1.0,2.0) = 3.0` -- but you seem to want to do something which would allow such a function to be written.

Comment: I'm a little confused - sml accepts the function as ('a * 'a -> 'a) -> 'a customList -> 'a which seems to be the type of function that I want.  It's when pass the list I created above that I get the error.  Is that what you expect as well?  Sorry, I'm just trying to understand what you mean

Comment: The problem is that in any definition in which `(op+)` is used the SML type system has to decide (for each occurrence of `+`) at compile time if integer addition or real addition is meant. I know of no way to defer that decision to run time.

Comment: Actually, I have what I want.  It wasn't working because instead of doing "addElements (op +) a;" I was doing "addElements a";.  The function I have above works for either real or ints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have works, but I don't think that it does what you think it does. For example,

```
addElements (op - ) customL(2, customL(1, customL(3,nothing)))
```

evaluates to 4, and

```
addElements (fn (x,y) => x) customL(2, customL(1, customL(3,nothing)))
```

evaluates to 2.

To see what is happening, temporarily forget about `customL`. That definition is fine but is isomorphic to `list`, so to see what is happening with your `addElements` it is less distracting to write it in terms of ordinary lists:

```
fun addElements (op + ) [] = raise Empty
|   addElements (op + ) [x] = x
|   addElements (op + ) (x::xs) = (op +)(x, addElements (op +) xs);
```

This is basically what you had, except that it uses pattern matching rather than a `let` binding. SML accepts this as:

```
val addElements = fn : ('a * 'a -> 'a) -> 'a list -> 'a
```

Note that the type has nothing really to do with either addition or even numbers (either int or real).

What is happening is that you are *redefining* `(op +)` in the body of the definition. SML makes heavy use of *predefined identifiers* as opposed to *reserved names*. The distinction seems pedantic, but it means that you are free to redefine just about anything:

```
val (op + ) = 5;
(op + ) * 7;
```

evaluates to 35.

In the body of the definition `(op +)` can be *any* function of type `'a * 'a -> 'a`. Thus -- using the symbol `+` and the name `addElements` is misleading. The most that could be said of it is that it reflects your intentions, but I don't think that this is a sufficient reason to redefine a built-in operator, even in a local scope.

A less misleading way to define your function would be more along the lines of:

```
fun combineElements combiner [] = raise Empty
|   combineElements combiner [x] = x
|   combineElements combiner (x::xs) = combiner (x,combineElements combiner xs);
```

Here the choice of names makes it clear that it is a polymorphic function which uses a function on ordered pairs to combine a list to a single item.

SML has a standard function `foldl` which does all this and slightly more:

```
- foldl (op + ) 0 [1,2,3];
val it = 6 : int
- foldl (op + ) 0.0 [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];
val it = 6.0 : real
- foldl (op +) 0 [];
val it = 0 : int
```

Note that it can handle the empty list. This is what I had in mind when I remarked in the comments that you seemed to be trying to do a sort of `fold` but one in which you wanted to hard-wire in the choice of addition as the operator.

Comment: Thank you for that!  I thought I could just switch out for - yeah.  So for combiner, I would replace that with combineElements + or combineElements (op +).  I think it's the latter.  Not by a pc at the moment.  I know about fold but was just trying different things with the list and got stuck with sum

Comment: @cpd1 You are correct that you need the (op +) syntax with comnineElements